# список из списков

Tags: c#, list, списки

доброго времени суток всем ,мне нужна небольшая помощь частично связано с вопросам номер 748904. проблема заключается в том ,сперва продемонстрирую код а затем проесню.

```
 class Program
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string lin = @"C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop\New folder (7)\flltest1.txt";
        using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(lin, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255")))

            while (true)
            {
                string HumDat;
                string temp = fs.ReadToEnd();
                bool activatr = true;
                Char delimiter = ',';
                String[] substrings = temp.Split(delimiter);
                List<List<string>> L = new List<List<string>>();
                List<string> TableD = new List<string>();
                int N,K,Q;
                Q = 0;
                N = 49;
                while (activatr)
                {
                    L.Add(TableD);
                    for ( K = Q; K < N; K++)
                    {
                        HumDat = Convert.ToString(substrings.GetValue(K));
                        TableD.Insert(K, HumDat);
                    }
                    Q = K;
                    N = K * 2;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

и так сама проблема в том что каждые 49 слов в тексте программа записывает в список но не просто список а по идее должен в двумерный список но увы этого не происходет после каждого 49 элемента он должес саписывать в новою строку  то есть  но так не происходит а происходет следующие создоетсяновый идентичный список но не как не новый с 49 элементами 
то есть конструкция токова:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Count 0 = 0-49                                                                                                     Count 1 = 49-98

Comment: А зачем `while (true)`, если за ним сразу `fs.ReadToEnd();`?

Answer (score 1):

`TableD` должно быть много ;) для каждого внутреннего списка свой :)
Вы :) всем вложенным присвоили один и тот же `TableD` и удивляетесь ;)

перед `L.Add(TableD)` нужно создать новый список :)

```
TableD = new List<string>();
L.Add(TableD);
```

Comment: Ответ по делу, хоть и очень на древний пост. Постарайтесь в будущем использовать меньше смайликов, одного вполне достаточно, особенно если это такой короткий ответ )